# How to automatically populate column headers with the date of a given month and year?

Tags: date, google-sheets, dropdown, sequence

I work on a daily management table for the positions (face-to-face, teleworking, training, etc.) of the membres of my team.
I enter the year in cell A1, then I select the month from a dropdown list in A2.
I would then like the headers of my columns to automatically fill with days date (which I will have formatted correctly [name of the day - date of the day without the year]).
I've searched several anser items on Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to match or want to work.

If anyone could enlighten me, that would be very nice of you !

My last attempt :

`=LET(dt;DATE(A1;MONTH(A2&1);1);IF(LEN(A1);SEQUENCE(1;EOMONTH(dt;0)-dt+1;dt);))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldQz5.png)

Link to a sample page :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxZVtAPc0Yh8VBfTFdEcwHzxN22paSpYPKABSplRryI/edit?usp=sharinga-given-month-and?noredirect=1#comment136742146_77564401

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I created a sample with the anonymous blank sheet maker and edited my original post. Thanks for the good practice tip !

Comment: Also do showcase the expected output (by entering it manually)

Comment: Done ! First days are empty because the december month of 2023 begin a Thursday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Added one approach [to the test sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxZVtAPc0Yh8VBfTFdEcwHzxN22paSpYPKABSplRryI/edit#gid=1166349538):*

```js
=let(Σ;date(A1;month(A2&1);1);
       torow({let(Λ;sequence(35;1;Σ-weekday(Σ;2)+1);index(if(month(Λ)=month(A2&1);Λ;)))\wrapcols(;35;)}))
```

- *couple of months like `jan 2023`, `oct 2023` may need 6 weeks setup for the entire 31 days to populate while the current design seems to accommodate 5 weeks only...*

[image]

Comment: A very interesting solution. I edited the pattern of the weeks and extended it to 6 weeks.
I am not familiar with torow and sequence. But I get an error :

Error
The function Parameter 2 of the ARRAY_ROW function has a row size inconsistency: 35 instead of 1.

Comment: change 35 (both places) to 42 (6 weeks*7 days) to accommodate 6 weeks setup.

Comment: Ok. I see what is wrong. My dropdown menu with months was not in the correct data format and therefore the selected month was not recognized correctly in the formula. It works correctly now. Thank you so much.